# How do I wield a weapon in two hands?

Tags: pc, dark-souls-2

I am playing dark souls 2 on pc. I remember i could wield a weapon in 2 hands while hiding my shield. I have forgotten how to do this.

I am trying to two hand a `great club`. Even if i put away my shield i still hold it in one hand.

How do you wield a weapon in two hands in dark souls 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the pc the default key to change weapon stance is 'n'. If you're playing on an Xbox pad then you need to press the Y button.

Comment: In the case of the controller, if you *hold* Y, it will two-hand your off-hand weapon, while tapping Y will two-hand your main. What is the case for PC?

Comment: It is the similar, you hold the N key instead of Y.

Comment: @Ben Keep in mind that when you hold the Y button (N on PC, assuming Triangle on PS), and Power Stance is possible, you will Power Stance instead of 2-handing your left hand weapon.